# Copy users from a series of groups based on a filter to another series of groups based on a separate filter

Tags: powershell, api, okta

Thanks for taking a minute to look at this.
Scenario: Copy users from a series of groups based on a filter to another series of groups based on a separate filter. Essentially a one for one copy of group memberships.

I created some code that grabs all the groups based on the filter and can get all of the users but am having a hard time translating that into the individual pieces. For each group I want just that groups members and then add them to a group with the same name but of a different type (one is OKTA_GROUP and the other is APP_GROUP).

Any help on this would be appreciated. Getting the groups and members works but putting those into variables and passing them into the PUT is not working.

Here is what I have so far.

```
function get-oktaInvokeGroupMembers () {
   $groups = Invoke-Method GET "/api/v1/groups?filter=type+eq+%22APP_GROUP%22&q=test"
    Write-Output $groups
      foreach ($group in $groups) {
        $members = Get-OktaGroupMember $group.id
      Write-Output $members
      }
   $oktagroups = Invoke-Method GET  "/api/v1/groups?filter=type+eq+%22OKTA_GROUP%22&q=Test"
   Write-Output $oktagroups
      foreach ($okta in $oktagroups) {
         Invoke-Method PUT "/api/v1/groups/$okta.id/users/$members.id"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get your APP_GROUP.
Then for each group, you loop to get the members with `Get-OktaGroupMember`. Each member has normally an `id`.
You need to retrieve the `OKTA_GROUP` which has the same name than the group you are currently processing to get its group `id`.
Then finally for each member, you put the member.

Something like that will be a good starting point.

```
function get-oktaInvokeGroupMembers ($groupName) {

   $sourceGroups = Invoke-Method GET "/api/v1/groups?filter=type+eq+%22APP_GROUP%22&q=$groupName"
   foreach ($sourceGroup in $sourceGroups) {
        
        $sourceMembers = Get-OktaGroupMember $sourceGroup.id
    
        $targetGroups = Invoke-Method GET  "/api/v1/groups?filter=type+eq+%22OKTA_GROUP%22&q=$groupName"
        
        foreach($targetGroup in $targetGroups) {

             foreach($sourceMember in $sourceMembers) {

                Invoke-Method PUT "/api/v1/groups/$($targetGroup.id)/users/$($sourceMember.id)"
             
             }    
        
        }
   }

}
```

I've defined a parameter `$groupName`.
I don't know your API but difficulty is that for a specific `groupName`, you may get zero, one or many groups as result.
So you need to handle all these cases. I've handled multiple results nesting `foreach` loop but in such case for one `APP_GROUP`, the script will set members on all `OKTA_GROUP` that have the same name than `APP_GROUP`. There may be zero, one or many `OKTA_GROUP` groups returned by the API.
Another point, you will probably need to handle errors when adding a member. Calling the API with `PUT` when the member is already in the `OKTA_GROUP` may return an error.
And last, the script will only append members to a group, but it will never "synchronize" both groups. Meaning deleting members isn't handled. If you need to synchronize members this is bit more complexe.

Comment: Thanks! Still trying to find time to test this out but it looks good and definitely helps me learn